# Eric Hynds jQuery UI Multiple Select Widget: Checkbox width is equal to the width of the text for every item

Tags: jquery

I use Eric Hynds' Multiple Select Widget and have an issue with the width of the Checkbox equal to the width of the text. The following is my code:

List of files included

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/redmond/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../Content/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/grid.common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/grid.formedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/dropmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML for the control:

```
<select id="SchemaName" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Code to populate the control. I am using a AJAX call since the data is from a database. I found this code in one of the samples on stackoverflow.

```
var $SchemaName_multiselect = jQuery('select#SchemaName').multiselect();
$SchemaName_multiselect.multiselect({ selectedList: 1 });

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function OnPopulateControl(data, response) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            jQuery.each(data, function () {
                jQuery('select#SchemaName').append(jQuery("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        } else {
            jQuery("select#SchemaName").empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
        }
        jQuery("select#SchemaName").multiselect('refresh');

        jQuery('select#SchemaName').unbind('multiselectclick').bind('multiselectclick', function (event, ui) {

            //ToDo: when the selection has changed.

            }

        });

    },
    error: function (data, response) {
        alert('Error: ' + response);
    }
});
```

The following is the screenshot:

[image: MultiSelect Issue]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing in your code:

```
      jQuery('select#SchemaName').append(jQuery("<option value=". val(this['Value']). "  selected='selected'>" .html(this['Text']) . "</option> ");
```

?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific as to what should I replace the code with?